# What is the best way to query a datetime field against date fields?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I just want to know what you guys are doing when you have a datetime field, ie:

> > Game.first.starts_at
> >         => Thu, 03 Dec 2009 20:20:00 EST -05:00

And you want to query it against a date field:

> > 3.days.from_now.to_date.to_s(:db)
> >         => "2009-12-03"

Currently I make this work by using the `BETWEEN` operator, but I would like to know more approachs to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Bobby, I'm sorry for the delay, both would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't bother with the `date.to_s(:db)` conversion. Working with pure `Date` and `Datetime` works fine for me.

```
Game.first(:conditions => ["starts_at <= ?", 3.days.from_now.to_date])
```

Comment: Hi, that's true, I just used  `date.to_s(:db)` to show the date format as "YYYY-MM-DD" instead of `Thu, 03 Dec 2009`. Thanks anyway :)