# Rails comparing dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a data model that contains a DateTime attribute, date. I want to find out if that date is today. I'm having a hell of a time!

```
>> Deal.first.date 
=> Mon, 14 Dec 2009 23:59:59 EST -05:00
```

I've tried so many techniques that I would be embarrassed to put them here. So I would just ask, what do I need to match this date in an ActiveRecord find method?

Thanks,
Aaron.

Comment: [my previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820677/what-is-the-best-way-to-query-a-datetime-field-against-date-fields) could help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing the time zone is driving you batty.

For a specific instance, you can do:

```
 model.date.today?
```

For an activerecord find, try this:

```
 Deal.all(:conditions=>['date > ?',Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day])
```

Here's the problem:

```
>> Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day == Date.today.beginning_of_day
=> false
```

Comment: This one works, both with and without the zone method inserted. Whooo! 

I don't think the zone settings were the problem though:

    Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day == Date.today.beginning_of_day
    => true

Comment: You deserve a medal for this. Date.today should be outlawed; removed from all documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this:

```
Deal.find(:first, :conditions => ['date >= ? AND date < ?', Date.today, Date.today+1])
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work, not sure if it will though, as I haven't tested it.

```
Deal.first(:condition => { :date => Date.today })
```

Comment: Oops, it should be `:conditions`, not `:condition`. You might also try this:
    Deal.first(:conditions => { :date => (Date.today)..(Date.today+1) })